# Php password hash()

Tags: php

What method can I apply if I want a user to edit their original password after storing as hash.

Comment: No. No no no. You don't want to do that, ever. There is no reason at all to show a user his password.

Comment: It is very dangerous...

Comment: You literally answered your question. *"I know it's a one-way function..."*

Comment: Your new edit I have answered in my answer. Just hash the new password and replace the new hash with the old hash in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**DO NOT** store an unhashed password in the database.

**DO NOT** show passwords in the 'change password form'

**DO NOT** show password hashes anywhere.

Provide the user with a form to edit the password but do not provide the previous one. Just show the user an empty text box for inserting a new password while also having a text box for the user to input their current password.

You can check any password hashed with `password_hash()` using `password_verify()`.

If `password_verify()` returns `true` just use an `UPDATE` query to change the stored hash.

Answer (score 3):

A website that shows a user their password is **VERY** insecure. **Always** hash it and **never** show the user their password. If they forget their password have the user reset their password and rehash it and replace it in their database. But **NEVER** show the user their password and **ALWAYS** hash.

Answer (score 1):

As for the suggestion of saving it, please, do never store unencrypted passwords in your database: every single of them will be exposed if your database is ever accessed.

As for your question: an encrypted or hashed word is very difficult (or plainly impossible, are you hashing or encrypting?) and costly to restore. I understand the usability issue but once a password is stored the user should never be able to query it (that's what we have password recovery measures)... So, in short, you could have them create new passwords but you can't have them editing the one they have since you don't even know it.

PS: All this assumes that the password is already been stored. Of course... If we're talking about html password tags the issue is different.